# PHP get last month name from a timestamp

Tags: php, date, unix-timestamp

I have a Unix timestamp and would like to get the name of the preceding month e. g. "Ferbruary"

```
$date = 1489842000;
$lastMonth = getLastMonth($date); //Ferbruary
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php) is your friend here:

```
echo Date('F', strtotime($date . " last month"));
```

For anyone that wants this fully dynamic, to always display last month's name, the code would be:

```
$currentMonth = date('F');
echo Date('F', strtotime($currentMonth . " last month"));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set a `DateTime` object to the specified timestamp, then subtract an interval of `'P1M'` (one month), like this:

```
/**
 * @param {int} $date unix timestamp
 * @return string name of month
 */
function getLastMonth($date) {
    // create new DateTime object and set its value
    $datetime = new DateTime();
    $datetime->setTimestamp($date);
    // subtract P1M - one month
    $datetime->sub(new DateInterval('P1M'));

    // return date formatted to month name
    return $datetime->format('F');
}

// Example of use
$date = 1489842000;
$lastMonth = getLastMonth($date);
```

Comment: It will be a better answer if you will explain your code there!

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @TobySpeight explanation added